# Can I use two S3 buckets for primary and secondary failover on Route53?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

I want to setup Route53 so that when people go to xyz.mydomain.com they will hit one of my two S3 buckets that I've setup with S3 replication.

I already have one of the buckets configured on Route53 but I'm not understanding how to configure the second one, like what do I put for the alias target?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We had the same issue to load balance s3 on outage and here is how it is resolved,

This is not just a failover, it is also active-active with latency based routing,

https://read.iopipe.com/multi-region-s3-failover-w-route53-64ff2357aa30

I thank **Erica Windisch** for this wonderful article.

The only disadvantage of the failover url is it can serve only on http and not https.

You can take the http and server over cloudfront to make it to https.

**'AWS is still pending giving a cleaner solution for this issue'**

Ideally, cnames should be accepted on multiple regions and automate the failover or latency based routing.

Hope it helps.

Comment: @casolorz If you have configured as it mentioned in the doc, you can take it to a CloudFront to use SSL and that will be a different domain than it is originally configured.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I'd solve it.

**Assumptions**

```
Main Region: us-east-1
Failover Region: us-west-2
```

**S3**

```
S3 Bucket 1:
  Name Suggestion: xyz.mydomain.com-failover
  Region: us-west-2
  Properties:
    Versioning: Enable Versioning
    Static Website Hosting: Use this bucket to host a website

S3 Bucket 2:
  Name: xyz.mydomain.com
  Region: us-east-1
  Properties:
    Versioning: Enable Versioning
    Static Website Hosting: Use this bucket to host a website
  Management:
    Replication:
      Add rule:
        Source:
          Source: All Contents
          Status: Enabled
        Destination:
          Destination Bucket: xyz.mydomain.com-failover
        Permissions:
          Select IAM Role: Create new Role
```

**CloudFront Distribution**

```
CloudFront Distribution:
  Type: Web
  Origin Settings:
    Origin Domain Name: xyz.mydomain.com-failover.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com
    Origin Id: S3-Failover-Bucket
  Distribution Settings:
    Alternate Domain Names (CNAMEs): xyz.mydomain.com
```

**Route 53**

```
Route 53 HealthCheck 1:
  Name: xyz.mydomain.com
  What to monitor: Endpoint
  Specify Endpoint by: Domain Name
  Protocol: HTTP
  Domain Name: xyz.mydomain.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com

Route 53 Record Set 1:
  Name: xyz.mydomain.com
  Type: CName
  Value: xyz.mydomain.com.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com
  Routing Policy: Failover
    Failover Record Type: Primary
    Associate with HealthCheck: Yes
      Health Check to Associate: xyz.mydomain.com

Route 53 Record Set 2:
  Name: xyz.mydomain.com
  Type: A
  Alias: Yes
    Alias Target:  [CloudFront Distribution for xyz.mydomain.com]
```

**(Optional) HTTPS Support**

Replace `xyz.mydomain.com` in the above with `abc.mydomain.com`

```
CloudFront Distribution:
  Type: Web
  Origin Settings:
    Origin Domain Name: abc.mydomain.com
    Origin Id: CrossRegionDomain
  Distribution Settings:
    Alternate Domain Names (CNAMEs): xyz.mydomain.com
```

**Rationale**

Any service that we point to with a Route 53 Record Sets must be able to handle requests for that domain.

At the time of writing, to host a website with S3, the name of the bucket had to be the domain you wanted S3 to respond to, which is why we named **S3 Bucket 2** `xyz.mydomain.com`.

Bucket names must be globally unique at the time of writing, so for **S3 Bucket 1**, we couple it with a CloudFront distribution so that the distribution is the one that knows how to respond to the domain. This is also why the name for S3 Bucket 1 is a suggestion.

For the optional HTTPS support, we wrap the solution in CloudFront, because this is standard practice for upgrading an S3 bucket to HTTPS support. CloudFront aliases also had to be globally unique at the time of this writing, which is why of we go support HTTPS, we have to rename the domain, at a bare minimum for **S3 Bucket 2**. We essentially take our failover solution and wrap it on CloudFront.

Comment: In the above, for Route 53 Record Set 2: I am not able to create a A record in the same name as xyz.mydomain.com? It says there is already a CName for xyz.mydomain.com

Answer (score 0):

> I want to setup Route53 so that when people go to xyz.mydomain.com
>   they will hit one of my two S3 buckets that I've setup with S3
>   replication.

This is not directly possible only using S3 and Route53 due to the AWS [limitation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/RoutingToS3Bucket.html) of requiring the bucket name as domain name in Route53 since you need to create two bucket names (Different one for replication in another region).

> The bucket must have the same name as your domain or subdomain. For example, if you want to use the subdomain acme.example.com, the name of the bucket must be acme.example.com.

The solution I would recommend would be(Assuming that you are doing the replication for High Availability and Fault Tolerance of S3 due to regulatory requirements) to have two AWS CloudFront distributions pointing towards the original and replicated bucket while having Failover routing configured towards the CNames of individual CloudFront distributions.

Having said that, failure of AWS S3 is highly unlikely due to the fact that, S3 is designed for 99.999999999% of durability and 99.99% (AWS provides SLA for 99.9%) of availability with internal redundant architecture and you need the above setup, only if there are unique regulatory requirements.

Comment: Never say S3 is reliable with availability. We lost total of $530K+ with its unavailability on us-east-1 region.Have it replicated across multiple regiong is a must for business now a days. It is not valid just for S3, it is the same for all of the services from AWS. We replicated to other regions and it paid off within few months of their small windows outages that happens all the time.

Comment: @Kannaiyan Great to know the insights on unavailability. How long was the outage you experienced?

Comment: https://techcrunch.com/2017/03/01/the-day-amazon-s3-storage-stood-still/  It was more than 12 hours in reality even though AWS claims it got sorted out in few hours. Ripple effect lasted longer than the availability time. Also funny thing was AWS dashboard was hosted on us-east-1 and it was not getting updated as well. https://techcrunch.com/2017/02/28/amazon-aws-s3-outage-is-breaking-things-for-a-lot-of-websites-and-apps/

Comment: @Kannaiyan thanks for that warning. I have set it up this way. Files on S3 west coast and replicated to EU (Frankfurt I think). I then have route 53 point to the west coast one as primary and secondary to a cloudfront entry that points to the Frankfurt S3 replication. I then have health checks for both S3 locations. And I have another cloudfront entry pointing to the route 53 domain so that I can use HTTPS. If I had had this setup back when that happened, would I have been ok?